# Prove that for every subset $ A $ of a topological space $ X $, $ \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(A)) $ is a regular open set.

Tags: general-topology

Ok, so I’m working through Willard’s *Topology* (I’m loving this book), and Problem 3D3 on Page 29 is as follows:

> Let $ X $ be equipped with a topology. Prove that for all $ A \subseteq X $, we have that $ \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(A)) $ is regular open, that is, $ \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(A)))) = \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(A)) $.

Here is my proof:
\begin{align*}
    \operatorname{Int}
    (
    \operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(A)))
    )
& = \operatorname{Int}
    (
    X \setminus
    (\operatorname{Int}(X \setminus (\operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Int}(A)))))
    ) \\
& = \operatorname{Int}
    (
    X \setminus
    (
    \operatorname{Int}
    (
    X \setminus
    (X \setminus (\operatorname{Int}(X \setminus \operatorname{Int}(A)))‌​)
    )
    )
    ) \\
& = \operatorname{Int}
    (
    X \setminus
    \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Int}(X \setminus \operatorname{Int}(A)))
    ) \\
& = \operatorname{Int}
    (X \setminus \operatorname{Int}(X \setminus \operatorname{Int}(A))) \\
& = \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(X \setminus \operatorname{Int}(A))) \\
& = \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Cl}(A‌​))) \\
& = \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(A)).
\end{align*}

I’m looking for alternative proofs, a proof verification and some deeper insights.

Thank you very much.

Regards.

Comment: I must confess do not follow the complementation equalities. Instead I'd argue by double inclusion, which gives the result readily.

Comment: Cl(B)=X-Int(X-B)

Comment: But look for instante to your $Int(Cl(X\setminus Int(A)))$. Since $Int(A)$ is open its complement is closed, hence $Cl(X\setminus Int(A))=X\setminus Int(A)$, so that in fact $Int(Cl(X\setminus Int(A)))=Int(X\setminus Int(A)$. This needn't be $Int(Cl(A))$ (look at an open interval in the line).

Comment: I never typed $int(cl(X \setminus  int (A))))$

Comment: In the last line of equalitites, second from the left?

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interior is the biggest open contained, hence from the obvious
$$\overline{\overset{\circ}{\overline A}}\supset\overset{\circ}{\overline A}$$ we get one inclusion. On the other hand, the closure is the smallest closed containing, hence
$$
{\overset{\circ}{\overline A}}\subset\overline{A}\quad\text{implies}\quad
\overline{\overset{\circ}{\overline A}}\subset\overline{A}
$$
and taking interiors we get the other inclusion.